# Mod deletion from review queue isn't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, moderator-tools, vote-to-delete

I just came across [a non-answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143551/31394) in the Low Quality Posts review queue on the site where I'm a mod. I clicked "Delete", picked one of the auto-comment options, and got a little red error message (whose text was something like "a problem occurred during deletion"). So I clicked "Delete" *again*, and got the same error message.

Then I went to the actual page the answer was on, and it was showing up with **three** pending delete votes - two mine and one earlier one from a non-mod 20k user - even though three is supposed to be enough to delete an answer even with no mod involved!

Finally another non-mod 20k user voted to delete and the post disappeared. We ended up with this weirdness:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, my voting to delete *twice* from the review queue was registered by the system (both comments show up, and I'm listed as one of the delete voters), but my reviews don't show up in the [review queue history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history), and for some reason **it didn't count as a binding mod vote.**

Maybe this is just a one-off issue, but I figured it was important enough to be worth reporting, if moderator deletions aren't working.

Comment: Reproduced: have to select delete *and* a canned comment, *and* it can't be the same as an existing canned comment. Review blows up trying to record the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a change made earlier to make LQ posts in review track review result status the same way as Suggested Edits do. Unfortunately that cause this problem.

I'm not 100% sure what the intent of the change was and it's Friday afternoon, so I'm reverting it until the dev who worked on it can review (ha!) on Monday and account for this case.

Comment: Thanks - this was a slightly scary bug! I don't understand exactly what change was being made though - what do you mean by "track review result status"?

Comment: For most reviews that allow comments, the comment is recorded under the post being reviewed in the same manner I'm leaving you this reply, @randal'thor. So when recording the review result, we just record with it the ID of the comment. However, this wouldn't make sense for suggested edits - so there's another, shorter, comment field there that gets filled in if someone rejects with a custom message. The problem arises when you try to stuff the contents of the former into the latter.

Comment: @Shog9 I hope comments are still going to be left when posts are deleted through review! The main reason I delete anything via review rather than directly from the post page or flag queue is so that I can leave that feedback for the OP (without having to go to the effort of writing out a non-auto-generated comment every time).

Comment: Yeah, that should be working again now, @randal'thor.